# How to search for all uGui scripts in scene in the Unity editor?

Tags: unity, asset-workflow

I have many game objects whose properties I need to edit because of a bug/error.

However, this is very time consuming, because I need to check each game object one by one.

Is there any way to search for all game objects that (for example) contain **uGui Scripts** in a scene?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Unity will allow you to use the search box at the top of the hierarchy panel to filter the hierarchy view to objects containing certain classes of script.

For instance, you can type "collider" to find all objects with a 3D collider like a BoxCollider, SphereCollider, etc. Or you can type "collider2d" to find objects with 2D colliders (which do not show up in the previous search, despite having the word "collider" in them, which makes it seem that Unity is recognizing this as the name of a parent class and searching for instances of any subclass, rather than checking whether each component name contains the search string).

To find UI components, you can either type the name of the specific component (eg. "image"), the name of a common base class (eg. "uibehaviour"), or a common component all UI objects share ("recttransform")